# Class library can't find MembershipUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've added a class library project to my application.

In one of my classes, I need to use the MembershipUser class, but the project can't find it. I've added references to System.Web, System.Web.Security, and System.Security.Principal.

I'm not sure what the problem is. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: can you show some of your code, please?

Comment: Can you confirm that you referenced System.Web version 2.0 or above? Also keep in mind, in asp.net 4.0 the class is in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you need to reference the `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll` assembly. As always the documentation of the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) contains all the necessary information:

```
Namespace:  System.Web.Security
Assembly:  System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)
```

In previous versions of the framework the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser(v=VS.85).aspx) class was located in the `System.Web.dll` assembly.

Comment: Thank you had the same problem. 2 hours looking what was the problem here. Have also a library project !

Comment: Thanks! it was helpful.