# Error while running a test: "You must add a reference to assembly..."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors

I am trying to launch a test but I obtain this error

> The type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I looked for google and found that I have to Add Reference `System.Web.ApplicationServices` to my project, i do it but still dont work.

I wrote it in web.config to but nothig, I obtain the same error

```
  <assemblies>
 <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
```

Any idea!!! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161203/where-is-system-web-security-membershipprovider    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708280/class-library-cant-find-membershipuser    Basically you can find this System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When do you get this problem?  When building your project, or when actually running the test?

If you get it when you build your project, follow these steps to see if it resolves your problem:

1 - Search your machine for this file: "System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.dll"

2 - Once you find it, open your project and choose the "Add Reference" menu command

3 - Choose the file you found in step 1

Comment: Thanks JosephStyons, but what happen if I don't have this file... System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.dll

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712467/net-4-0-system-web-security-membershipprovider-ambiguous-reference) might help as well.