# Where is System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0

I have a library project that should be the base for several web applications. I am trying to implement System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider but for some reason Visual Studio cannot find it. It manages to find System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider but not MembershipProvider.

Any idea why?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Starting in .NET 4, [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is declared in **System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll** (strangely enough), so you need to add a reference to that assembly. In .NET 3.5 and earlier, MembershipProvider is declared in System.Web.dll.

---

**Tip:** To find out which assembly contains any .NET Framework class, just search for the class in MSDN Library. Here's what the [MembershipProvider page for .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

> **Namespace:** System.Web.Security
>   **Assembly:** System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)

And here's what the [MembershipProvider page for .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says:

> **Namespace:** System.Web.Security
>   **Assembly:** System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

Comment: Resharper tries to suggest adding System.Web.Security, to which it adds the code, but doesn't find the reference. Manaully adding the reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices works a treat. Thank you.